# In-App Billing switching activities

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, android-activity, in-app-billing

Ahh the in-app billing problems never end! ^.^ I have everything working properly to show the transaction page for the in-app purchase. If I complete the purchase it returns me to my application and after about 10 seconds it verifies the purchase and I receive the item.

On the other hand, if I press the back button after returning to the application and switch to another activity it never processes the transaction. Even if I return to the in-app billing activity I never receive my purchased item, like the purchase has been completely forgotten about if you call finish().

What can I do so that it either completes the transaction and gives the item when I return to the in-app billing activity or processes the transaction and gives the purchased item anywhere that I am at within my application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Receiving the notification is handled by a broadcast receiver which is independent from your activities. How you handle the notification is up to you. In the default implementation you have a `PurchaseObserver` interface implemented by an Activity. You can have multiple activities implement it and register to be called accordingly. Or, you can have related code in a base activity, so that all your activities are `PurchaseObserver`'s (might not be practical if you have a lot of activities).

Comment: What I got working was placing the handler in my home activity, which is always up as long as my application is running, so that no matter what activity I am on the notification handler can always be accessed.

Comment: The preferred idiom is to register the as an observer `onStart()` and unregister `onStop()`, so you shouldn't rely on an activity that is not visible to handle this. You can do any changes to a DB, etc. from a service, but if you need to update the UI (remove ads, etc), each activity should be able to handle it, not rely on the home activity.